# How to share Asynchronous JS file Object value to LWC JS file?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-wire-adapter

I have created a LWC where I am making callout using Fetch API. Callout is working as expected when I use single JS file.
Now, I want to split my logic in JS into sub JS file as we can create Multiple JS file in LWC.

**LWC Component Name : testLwcComp**

**In TestLwcComp.js:**

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { fetchData } from "./fetchData"; //calling fetchData JS file
export default class TestLwcComp extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: "$recordId",
        fields: [someFields]
    })
    wireInfo({ error, data }) {
        if (error) {
        } else if (data) {
            let info = fetchData();
            console.log("info:" + info);
        }
    }
}
```

**fetchData.JS(added in same LWC testLwcComp):**

```
let information={};
export function fetchData(){
        fetch(endpoint)
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
            console.log(data)
            information= {
             a: data.a,
             b:data.b,
             c:data.c
            }
        })
        .catch(error=>console.error(error));
        return information;
    }
```

Now in info console log of  TestLwcComp.js, I am getting value as Undefined and then fetchData.JS gets executed since it has Asynchronous callout.

To control the sequence I am trying to use async await here:

```
let info = async =>{
let data;
data = await fetchData();
return data;
}
```

but It's still not working.

Can someone please tell me how can I fetch the value in info debug logs? What I am doing wrong here?

Instead of Fetch API call, If I try to return some value(synchronous execution), I can retrieve value in **info** console log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to slightly tweak your code. In the utils file, declare the function as `async` and `await` the fetch call.

```
export default async function fetchData(url = '', params = {}) {
    const response = await fetch(url);

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response.json();
}
```

and in your code, you can either use async/await or use promise-based invocation.

```
async makeCallout(){
    try{
        let response = await fetchData('http://www.google.com');
        console.log(response);
    } catch(e){
        // handle error
    }

    // or use a promise based invocation

    fetchData('http://www.google.com').then((data)=>{
        // do something
    }).catch((err) => {
        // handle error
    });
}
```

I have implemented a similar pattern [in this file](https://github.com/adityanaag3/planning-poker-heroku/blob/master/src/client/modules/ui/gamePlay/gamePlay.js).

However, a small suggestion based on your code snippet - Looks like you're making a callout after the data is provisioned using a wire service. I would recommend moving the callout logic also to Apex, and use a single wire call to get both the data from Salesforce and the API as well.. Making API calls from JS exposes secrets like Auth Tokens that you may send, and also you may run into CORS issues.

Comment: Wire setting has Custom Metadata values which I have to pass before making call out such as Endpoint, Token etc. I will modify the code suggested by you and get back to you in sometime. About CORS issue, 3rd party has white listed our URL and I also added the same in CSP so currently not facing an issue. But will try to add some custom setting switch here either make Apex callout or Fetch Call.

Comment: Given that there is a token involved, I would recommend moving the callout to Apex.. Anyone can use Developer Tools on Chrome and gain access to the token... In any case, the snippets I gave above should solve the issue you're having with async callouts.

Comment: if I use Default keyword, then I get an error while deploying the code fetchData is not exported by fetchData.js, imported by TestLwcComp.js. If I remove default keyword from fetchData.js then I can deploy the code but it's not calling the fetchData.js file. The issue is still there :(

Comment: Try the import this way - import fetchData from './fetchUtils'; - for default exports you don't need curly braces. If it still doesnt work, please update the question with the latest code, and I will take a look

Comment: It worked but now getting an exception that response.json() is not a function that we are returning

Comment: I have figured out the issue. Instead of returning response.json(), I have to return response then use .then(response=>response.json()) after the fetch. Now I can capture the payload in my wire of main LWC JS file. Can you make changes in your code so that I can mark it as a best answer?

Comment: What you said about the token & moving callout to apex, Did you mean that Fetch API is not secured? Reason I am using Fetch API here is to avoid server calls. Just FYI, I am before making fetch call, I am generating token from Apex Callout(separate callout we have to generate the token and we get new token in every 15 mins) then I am using this token in My Fetch API. We have IP restrictions in our application, Do you think It is still not secure to make callout using Fetch?

Comment: Strange. I just tried in my org, and the exact same code works for me, without adding `.then(response=>response.json())`. Answering your other question - If your component is shown only to logged-in users, its ok in a way. If it was shown to guest users, then definitely its not secure. The only concern being, what if somebody copies your access token from the browser and makes a callout themselves.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In the last code segment you posted

```
let info = async =>{
let data;
data = fetchData();
return data;
}
```

There is no await.

would this maybe help?

```
let info = async =>{
let data;
data = await fetchData();
return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Pointing it out. I have updated the code. Still the issue is there